# Mysql order date by the m/h/s

Tags: mysql

How to order date, like this - 2012-02-01 00:00:00 by the hour,minutes,and the seconds, not by the year/moth/day.

If i have..

```
2012-02-01 02:00:00
2012-03-01 20:00:00
2012-04-01 12:00:00
2012-05-01 07:00:00
```

I wan't to get this output.

Column tipe is timestamp.

```
   2012-02-01 02:00:00
    2012-05-01 07:00:00
    2012-04-01 12:00:00
    2012-03-01 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY TIME(date_column)
```

This will, however, slow down your queries, as it isn't possible to index the on-the-fly calculation. If you have a lot of records, or if this query runs frequently, you should break the time portion of the date into its own column so you can index it for faster sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TIME()` function to extract the time portion of the expression passed, e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT TIME('2012-02-01 02:00:00');
    -> '02:00:00'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time